# how to remove " " from json format

Tags: c#

```
{
    "ResCode": 1,
    "ResStrDisplay": "{"
    EmpId ":16,"
    FullName ":"
    GTPTEST ","
    Designation ":"
    Software Engineer ","
    LastActivity ":"
    Sign in recorded at 02 / 12 / 2016 15: 23 from IP address: 115.118.170.121 "}"
}
```

I want to output like following:

```
{
    "ResCode": 1,
    "ResStrDisplay": {
        "EmpId": 16,
        "FullName": "GTPTEST",
        "Designation": "Software Engineer",
        "LastActivity": "Sign in recorded at 02/12/2016 15:23 from IP address: 115.118.170.121"
    }
}
```

so how to remove inverted comma before `"{"Emplid":1,...}"` before `bracket` and after `breaket` inveted comma how to remove it.

Comment: Basically, what you've got isn't JSON. You should find whatever is producing it, and get them to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
string s = yourInput;
string fixS = s.Replace("\"{\"", "{");
```

Answer (score 0):

As Jon mentioned, what you have is really not JSON. Fixing the weird format is really not a good solution, and is very fragile and error prone.

But for some reason, if you cannot absolutely absolutely have the "incorrect-json-like-string-producer-source-system" fix the string, then your problem has less to do with JSON parsing and more towards string cleansing..

In that case, try this snippet:

```
    // this is a quick-fix and really not a good solution.
    // opt for this, only if you cannot absolutely fix the
    // source system and want the resultant string urgently

    var reallyNotJson_JustSomeJsonLikeImposterString = "YOUR_JSON_LIKE_STRING";

    var jsonString = reallyNotJson_JustSomeJsonLikeImposterString
            .Replace("\"{\"", "{")
            .Replace("\"}\"", "}")
            // comment out the following 2 lines, if you don't want to
            // normalize your keys.. it will still be valid JSON
            .Replace("\r\n    ", string.Empty)
            .Replace(" \"", "\"");

   // you can now JSON deserialize  jsonString
```